# In Linux we have /etc/environment for storing global variable. In FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, environment-variables

In Linux when I need to store a variable globally I use `/etc/environment`. What's the corresponding file in FreeBSD? I've seen this https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/new-users/your-working-environment.html but that didn't give me any clue.

Comment: What problem are you _actually_ trying to solve?  `/etc/environment` is nowhere near universal, not even all Linux distributions use it.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, re-read my question.

Comment: Please describe the problem, not the solution as you imagine it.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, it's already described -- **I need to store a variable globally** .open your eyes.

Comment: There is no way to do that.  Please explain why you _think_ you need global environment variables.  And consider dropping that attitude before asking for help.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, that's incorrect. And consider becoming simplier.

Comment: `/etc/environment` is not available on Fedora/Redhat/CentOS and other downstream Linux distributions. There is no general mechanism in Linux for storing variables. How you do it depends on your shell or application.

Comment: @SatoKatsura and fpmurphy1 are correct. "environment" is depending on the shell used and if it is interactive or not. The question is unclear, You would get better answers if you showed willingness to clarify the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option would be, as on Linux, to set the environment variables in the system's shell initialization files under `/etc`.  For `sh`-compatible login shells, this would be in `/etc/profile`, while for `csh` shells it would be `/etc/csh.cshrc` as explained in the article that you linked to.

The login environment may also be set in `/etc/login.conf`.  This is not a shell script but the *login class capability database*, so it follows a strict format. You should read [`man login.conf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=login.conf&sektion=5&n=1) before trying to modify it.

To add two environment variables, `VAR1` and `VAR2`, to this file, you choose what login class to modify and add

```
:setenv=VAR1=value1,VAR2=value2:
```

When done, run `cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf` as root as described in the manual.

Notice that the default path is *not* set with `setenv`.

Comment: and for `tcsh`?

Comment: hence, what should I use "/etc/csh.login" or "/etc/login.conf" for global variables?

Comment: @user7905648 `tcsh` also uses `/etc/csh.login`.  As the administrator of your system, you use whatever way you want to add variables. Personally, I would modify the shell initialization scripts rather than `/etc/login.conf`, but I don't know what requirements you have.

Comment: requirement: set a variable avaiable to all the users. automatically, when a system boots, hence I won't have to set it each time after I reboot a system.

Comment: `while for csh shells it would be /etc/csh.login` -- for which user?

Comment: @user7905648 I've edited it to `/etc/csh.cshrc`.  Every invocation of `csh` and `tcsh` by any user reads that file.

Comment: `To add two environment variables, VAR1 and VAR2, to this file, ` - which file? if that's  not `/etc/csh.cshrc`, how to add to an env. var. to `/etc/csh.cshrc`?

Comment: @user7905648 `setenv VAR1 "value"` on a line in the file (`/etc/csh.cshrc`).

Comment: I find in most cases mopst preferable to make changes to /usr/local/share/skel YMMV

Comment: @ClausAndersen That will set variables for future new accounts, yes (unless the account holders change their files). It won't affect existing users though.

Comment: @Kusalananda - sure! Your solution also requires that they log out/in after your change. There are always caveat emptors. But I stated this option as it is often underused. I have seen many setting a "default" because they did not know about skel.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and was curious how it was accomplished on Ubuntu systems. The answer is via [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/). The LinuxPAM module [pam_env](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html) does this.

FreeBSD uses [OpenPAM](https://www.openpam.org/) which does not seem to have this module.

FreeBSD does have [login.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?login.conf(5)) but this will not be as universal as `pam_env`. It won't set environment variables for cron jobs for instance.

The answer, I'm afraid, is that you can't at the moment. And the reason why it's not universal even on Linux systems is the `pam_env` isn't configured on all Linux systems.